# Deserialization of Untrusted Data in JMS Security Issue

Tags: java, security, jms, ibm-mq

I am using a bean for sending mails in my Java EE application. My class for sending mails is generated through xDoclet. Class code is given below

```
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message)   {
           MapMessage mapMsg = (MapMessage) message;
           String toEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("toAddress");
           String ccEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("ccAddress");
           String from = mapMsg.getString("from");
           String subject = mapMsg.getString("subject");
           String content = mapMsg.getString("body");
   }
```

Now, I have got some security issues in checkmarx for this class as - Deserialization of Untrusted Data in JMS at lines

```
String toEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("toAddress");
String ccEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("ccAddress");
```

Comment: IBM MQ Classes for JMS has to trust the call to Deserialize to a string which will call Java code, by default it will trust anything.  IBM MQ Classes for JMS has a feature where you can deny all and white list trusted classes, but I'm not sure if this will solve the warning or not.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the Checkmarx query for Deserialization of Untrusted Data in JMS, add a try catch block when casting and check if message is not an instance of ObjectMessage:

```
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message)   {    
 try {    
    if !(message instanceOf ObjectMessage){
               MapMessage mapMsg = (MapMessage) message;
               String toEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("toAddress");
               String ccEmailAddress = mapMsg.getString("ccAddress");
               String from = mapMsg.getString("from");
               String subject = mapMsg.getString("subject");
               String content = mapMsg.getString("body");
    }
 }
 catch {}
 finally {}
}
```

Comment: No luck with try and catch block

Comment: @user8358111 Were you able to fix the issues?

Comment: @Harry were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in checkmarx adding the validation `instanceof TextMessage` in `onMessage` implementation:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                ....
            catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So @securecodeninja 's answer was correct, right? Cool. Happy that you could able to fix it.